# Get error FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security, angularfire2

I develop web app using Angular 8 and connect to firebase using @angular/fire v5.4.2 and firebase js SDK v7.8.0. Every time I want to get a document in firestore it always shows error

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at new FirestoreError (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:130146:28)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.push.../../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:145520:16)
    at JsonProtoSerializer.push.../../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:146033:44)
    at PersistentListenStream.push.../../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:142655:43)
    at https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:142584:30
    at https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:142624:28
    at https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:131493:20
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3690:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (https://localhost:4200/vendor.js:83071:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (https://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:3689:52)
```

Here is my code when trying to get the document

```
loginFirebase(): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().then(res => {
      resolve(res);
    }).catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}

login(username: string, password: string): Promise<IUsers> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.loginFirebase().then(userLogin => {
        this.setUser(res).then(() => {
           resolve();
        }).catch(err => {
           reject(err);
        });
     }).catch(errorFirebase => {
        reject(errorFirebase);
     });
  }
}

setUser(data: UserLogin): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const userData: IUsers = {
        userId: data.doctor.id.toString(),
        userFullName: `${data.doctor.firstName} ${data.doctor.lastName}`,
        userPhoto: data.doctor.profileImage || '',
        userStatus: UserStatus.ACTIVE,
        userType: data.roles[0].role,
        token: data.token,
        sex: data.doctor.sex,
        email: data.name
      };
      try {
        this.afStore.collection(`${environment.firestoreCollection}users`, ref => ref.where('userId', '==', userData.userId.toString()))
          .get()
          .subscribe(doc => {
            resolve(doc)
          }, err => {
             console.error(err);
          });
       } catch (error) {
          this.translate.get('error_message', {error: 'catch saveUser'}).subscribe(err => {
             if (confirm(err)) {
                this.setUser(data);
             } else {
                reject(error);
             }
          });
       }
```

And here is the rules for the firestore

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAuth(request);
    }
    
    function isAuth(req) {
      return req.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

When the web app signed in anonymously, I check the uid it's already in firebase authentication. What possibly I get wrong here? Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: FYI you don't need to wrap all those existing promises in new promises.  The promises returned by the Firebase SDK will resolve or reject on their own without all that extra code.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for the feedback. I'll change it later. :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to determine when the user is actually signed in and able to make authenticated queries.  It turns out that the promise returned by `signInAnonymously` isn't actually an indicator if the user is fully signed in.

Comment: So you mean after I call `signInAnonymously` I need to call `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` to make sure the user has successfully logged in??

Comment: You can set up an observer whenever you want.  The callback you provide will be invoked whenever the sign-in state of the user changes.

Comment: I've tried it, but unfortunately I still get the same error...

Comment: Could you please edit the code provided in your description after the changes you have performed based on the suggestion above?